# Saving data from a html form to List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two `Create` methods one decorated with `HttpGet`, and the other with `HttpPost`. I have a create view for the first one looking like this :

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txt" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />   
</form>
```

The methods :

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "element1", "element2", "element3" };
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string txt)
    {
        //myList.Add(Request.Form["txt"]);
        myList.Add(txt);
        return View();
    }
```

I am simly trying to pass the data from my form on button to my second `Create()` and save it to `myList`.

I need some advice on how to make this work.

Comment: .. what isn't working? That seems to work perfectly fine (assuming your `<form action` attribute is set to the `Create` action or is blanked (so it posts back to itself).

Comment: @RudiVisser It is just not adding to the list

Comment: @RobertRoss What you mean "not adding"? On the second request `myList` contains only default values?

Comment: I am aiming to add a more elements using the form.

Comment: You are, but only for that single request. You're not doing anything with them. If you want to store them, consider using `Session` for development, I'll post a sample.

Comment: I think that the problem is that on every request your controller reinitialized. So one of the possible solutions is make `myList` static or move to another class.

Comment: You can use a Cache or database to store your data. Also, change `public ActionResult Create(string txt)` to `public ActionResult Create()` since you are using `Request.Form`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've fixed your form (in that you're posting back to your application's default route (by default `HomeController.Index()` method) by sending the request to /, instead of your `Create` method), you are actually correctly adding the value to your list. The problem is, that value only stays for the current request.

To make things persistent, you need to consider a persistence layer in memory, in database, or in session. I've provided a full sample below that uses the session, which will give you a per-user list instance. Without this layer, your Controller is being routinely disposed of once the action has completed processing, and so the amends to your list are not persisted. This is the normal request lifecycle in ASP.NET and makes sense when you consider that your app is basically only ever dealing with 1 request at a time. It's important to note that making something `static` isn't a form of persistence per-se, in that its lifetime and reliability is indeterminable. It will appear to work, but once your application pool recycles (ie. the app is destroyed and reloaded in memory) you will have again lost all amends to your list.

I would suggest you read up on [Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to understand exactly what is going on below. In a nutshell, each application user / unique visitor to your site will be given a unique 'session ID', you can then use this session ID to store data that you wish to use on the server side. This is why, if you were to visit your `Create` method from separate browsers (or try Private mode) you will be maintaining two separate lists of data.

View (which also outputs the list to the user):

```
@model List<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach(var str in Model)
    {
        <li>@str</li>
    }
</ul>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="txt" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Controller contents:

```
public List<string> MyList
{
    get
    {
        return (List<string>)(
            // Return list if it already exists in the session
            Session[nameof(MyList)] ??
            // Or create it with the default values
            (Session[nameof(MyList)] = new List<string> { "element1", "element2", "element3" }));
    }
    set
    {
        Session[nameof(MyList)] = value;
    }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(MyList);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string txt)
{
    MyList.Add(txt);
    return View(MyList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)){
     <input type="text" name="txt" value="" />
     <input type="submit" />  
}
```

Replace `Controller` with your Controller name.

Or simply use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
     <input type="text" name="txt" value="" />
     <input type="submit" />  
}
```

**When you call `BeginForm()` without any parameters it default to using the same controller/action used to render the current page.**